# Identify the "Firefox View" tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Recently Firefox has introduced a "Firefox View" tab which is like a persistent pinned tab that cannot be closed (except disabling it in the View menu) or navigated out of. This tab is returned by `browser.tabs.query`.

I want to identify it so it will not be processed by the extension. `url` property is not a viable option since any tab can be navigated to `about:firefoxview`

I have noticed that it has `hidden` set as true. `hidden` seems to only be a property in the Firefox API, Chrome does not have it. The documentation does not say much about it, but "whether the tab is hidden" - whatever that means (I checked that it is not associated with the tab being in the scrolled out of view section of the tabbar).

So is checking the `hidden` property to identify the tab a viable option? Or could other tabs also be "hidden"? Are there any better options?

It's properties:

```
active: false
​​
attention: false
​​
audible: false
​​
cookieStoreId: "firefox-default"
​​
discarded: false
​​
favIconUrl: "chrome://branding/content/icon32.png"
​​
height: 746
​​
hidden: true
​​
highlighted: false
​​
id: 11
​​
incognito: false
​​
index: 1
​​
isArticle: undefined
​​
isInReaderMode: false
​​
lastAccessed: 1667374495857
​​
mutedInfo: Object { muted: false }
​​
pinned: false
​​
sharingState: Object { camera: false, microphone: false, screen: undefined }
​​
status: "complete"
​​
successorTabId: -1
​​
title: "Firefox View"
​​
url: "about:firefoxview"
​​
width: 1351
​​
windowId: 63
```

Comment: Check that its favIconUrl equals the value shown in your post.

Comment: It's the same problem as the url property - about:firefoxview can be opened in a regular tab.

Comment: Hmm, but it's opened in its own tab, so checking the url should be enough. If I have just one tab, clicking the view opens a second tab.

Comment: Yes, but you can open a new tab and type about:firefoxview. Also I see now that there are `tabs.show()` and `tabs.hide()` experimental methods and this is what the `hidden` property is for.

Comment: There's probably no way. Try suggesting to implement in on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org